# Models of pretoposes vs. models of coherent categories

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory, categorical-logic

I'm confused about [these lecture notes](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/278xnotes/Lecture8-Topologies.pdf). Theorem 4 states, roughly, that for each coherent category $C$ there is a pretopos $C^\mathrm{eq}$ such that for any pretopos $D$, morphisms of coherent categories $C\to D$ correspond to morphisms of coherent categories $C^\mathrm{eq}\to D$.

In the same theorem it says:

> In particular, [...] induces an equivalence of categories $\mathrm{Mod}(C^\mathrm{eq})\to \mathrm{Mod}(C)$.

Confusing point: Definition 2 defines models of a pretopos $P$ as morphisms of *pretoposes* $P\to\mathbf{Set}$. But since Theorem 4 only talks about morphisms of coherent categories I think both $\mathrm{Mod}$s in the above quote are meant to be models in the sense of Definition 8 from [Lecture 5](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/278xnotes/Lecture5-Booleanization.pdf) and not in the sense of Definition 2. Is that right?

Second question: for each coherent category $C$ is there a pretopos $C'$ such that for any pretopos $D$, morphisms of coherent categories $C\to D$ correspond to morphisms of pretoposes $C'\to D$? If yes, as a special case one would get that the category of models of $C'$ *as a pretopos* (Definition 2 in Lecture 8) are the same as models of $C$ *as a coherent category*. Isn't that more natural anyway? Or can you convince me with arguments that Theorem 4 is really what one wants to say?

(Another confusing point is that the notes speak about weak syntactic categories, which are coherent categories in these notes, of *first-order theories*. But coherent categories correspond to [coherent logic](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/coherent+logic) and not first-order logic.)

Comment: Exercise 1 says that morphisms of pretoposes are the same as morphisms of coherent categories (that happen to be pretoposes).

Comment: Thanks, Zhen Lin!